# NSFetchedResultsController predicate NOT filtering part of it (using ANY, IN and BETWEEN in the same fechRequest's predicate)

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've searched a lot here and couldn't find a solution to my situation:

I have a TableViewController that uses NSFetchedResultsController to display data from CoreData.

The model has an entity "Places" that has a to-many relationship called "Types" (and an inverse one, also to-many relationship).

In a first TableViewController I display the objects from entity "types" (each place can belong to more than one type, and one type can have more than one place). When the user taps on a row it calls a new TableViewController that will show objects from entity "Places" related to "Types" using a NSFetchedResultsController.

I know I could just use:

```
NSSet = [aType valueForKey:@"Places"];
```

However, I really want to use the NSFetchedResultsController and all its benefits.

Well, at the NSFetchedResultsController accessor method I was able to recreate this relationship by using:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Places" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSDictionary *types = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.theTypes, @"TYPES", nil];
NSPredicate *predicateAny = [NSPredicate 
                             predicateWithFormat:@"ANY types IN $TYPES"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [predicateAny predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:types];
```

This code works fine as it returns "Places" that are related to the "Types" I want (those were hold inside the property theTypes). I use a property (theTypes), in the TableViewController to hold all "Types" objects one selected at the original tableViewController.

The problem is that the entity "Places" has a property named "distance" that I also need to use as a filter inside the NSPredicate, like this:

```
NSNumber *radious = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:10000.00];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance BETWEEN {0 , %@}", radious];
NSDictionary *types = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.theTypes, @"TYPES", nil];
NSPredicate *predicateAny = [NSPredicate 
                             predicateWithFormat:@"ANY types IN $TYPES"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [predicateAny predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:types];
NSPredicate *thePred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate, pred,  nil]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:thePred];
```

Here's where the problem occurs: the "distance" filter appears to be simply ignored by the predicate at the fetchRequest. The resulted fetch always has Places that don't match the @"distance BETWEEN {0 , %@} clause.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing here?

Thanks a lot!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

This predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicateAny = [NSPredicate 
                             predicateWithFormat:@"ANY types IN $TYPES", 
                             radious];
```

Doesn't make sense because you don't use the `radious` variable in this predicate. Not sure if that is the source of the problem but you should clean it up anyway.

This predicate:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance BETWEEN {0 , %@}", radious];
```

... could probably be:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance <=%@", radious];
```

... unless you have the possiblity of a negative `radious` value. It will be much faster that way.

Comment: Thanks TechZen! But you are right, the radious thing is a typo (i've edited the original post to avoid errors again). About the second observation you made, yes, I need to test for values under 0, so the BETWEEN {0 , %@} part is important...

Comment: Looks like the distance parameter must be a dumb one. I mean, the code must first calculate the distance for all coreData entries, and only than be used inside the predicate. That way the comparison would work. The way my dataModel was built the distance field had custom accessor methods that would calculate the distance from a given coordinate. I can't do that during a predicate and a fetch. This filed (distance), must be a simple one, just holding static data. So, the distance calculation must be done BEFORE the fetch, making the predicate valid.